# Magento Connect Manger : CONNECT ERROR: PHP Extensions "zlib" must be loaded

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu-14.04

While installing Extension and themes and also trying to upload, I am getting

> CONNECT ERROR: PHP Extensions "zlib" must be loaded.

I have tried to installed zlib from here: https://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html

zlib is installed in My Ubuntu:

[image]

Also enabled and loaded in PHP ini:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Go to GZ.php file ( downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Gz.php ) in your Magento directory 
and replace

```
if (!function_exists('gzopen')) {
```

with

```
if (!function_exists('gzopen64')) {
```

and also:

```
$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);
```

with

```
$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen64($this->_filePath, $mode);
```

Comment: It's not working i am getting same errors can you please best solutions @Prafulla Kumar Sahu